# More elegant code than multiple if (){do} checks

Tags: java, android, optimization

Can the following behavior, combining three criteria, be achieved with more elegant solution. If read a lot that switch case is bad smell and if else would get to nested.

```
    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Switch sr = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ros);
    Switch srs = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ros_stream);
    boolean wifi_state = isConnected(this);
     if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros & buttonView.isChecked() & wifi_state) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ros intent ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros & buttonView.isChecked() & !wifi_state) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "log: wifi bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        sr.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros & !buttonView.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ros intent stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        srs.setChecked(false); // and stop ros intent, automatically calls onCheckedChange again
    }
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros_stream & buttonView.isChecked() & sr.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "stream intent ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros_stream & buttonView.isChecked() & !sr.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "log: first switch is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        srs.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros_stream & !buttonView.isChecked()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "stream intent stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // and stop stream intent
    }
}
```

Comment: for one, you can start using && instead of && and yoiu can replace sr.isChecked() == true with simply sr.isChecked()

Comment: I edited the code. If i use one & the if starts to abort after first false, i dont want that

Comment: You are still repeating checks, while you could do use nested if statements, you're not using else, meaning you'll run checks without needing to check them, and you still use & instead of &&, meaning you'll still check conditions while you (could) already know the condition will return false. Elegant is good, efficënt is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would roll them out into an `enum`. Here's the first two done for you.

```
enum Check {

    IntentReady {

                @Override
                boolean check(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean wifi_state) {
                    return buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros & buttonView.isChecked() & wifi_state;
                }

                @Override
                void apply(Switch sr, Switch srs) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ros intent ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            },
    WIFIBad {

                @Override
                boolean check(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean wifi_state) {
                    return buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros & buttonView.isChecked() & !wifi_state;
                }

                @Override
                void apply(Switch sr, Switch srs) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "log: wifi bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sr.setChecked(false);
                }

            };

    abstract boolean check(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean wifi_state);

    abstract void apply(Switch sr, Switch srs);
}

public void onCheckedChangedNew(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Switch sr = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ros);
    Switch srs = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ros_stream);
    boolean wifi_state = isConnected(this);
    for ( Check c : Check.values()) {
        if ( c.check(buttonView, wifi_state)) {
            c.apply(sr, srs);
        }
    }
}
```

The primary benefit here is that you can transform the code robotically. Once done you have more flexibility and clarity.

Comment: Very elegant - love this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros)
    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
        if (wifi_state) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ros intent ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "log: wifi bad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sr.setChecked(false);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ros intent stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        srs.setChecked(false); // and stop ros intent, automatically calls onCheckedChange again
    }
} else
if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros_stream) {
    if (buttonView.isChecked()) {
        if (sr.isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "stream intent ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "log: first switch is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            srs.setChecked(false);
        }        
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "stream intent stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // and stop stream intent
    }
}
```

This removes the unnecessary checks (@Stultuske) and is little bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored your code a bit, with the changes I suggested in the comments:

```
    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    Switch sr = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ros);
    Switch srs = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_ros_stream);
    boolean wifi_state = isConnected(this);

    String text = "";
    if ( buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros){
    if ( buttonView.isChecked()){
        text = wifi_state ? "ros intent ready":"log: wifi bad";
        if ( !wifi_state){
        sr.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    else{
        text = "ros intent stopped";
        sr.setChecked(false);
    }

    }
    else if ( buttonView.getId() == R.id.switch_ros_stream){
    if ( buttonView.isChecked()){
        text = sr.isChecked() ? "stream intent ready" : "log: first switch is off";
        if ( !sr.isChecked()){
        srs.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    else{
        text = "stream intent stopped";
    }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```